# *new title: JButton array scope (it was:change color of button with button name)

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

How can is alter the color of the correct button?
It is for a small application, this app has 5 buttons from a array.(the name's are a,b,c,d,e)

The appearence of the buttons have to alter (change color) when i type in a number in a Jtextfield.

I added a name to each button:

```
knop = new JButton(Titel[i]);
            knop.setName(tel[i]);
```

Here i get the text:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String invoer = antwoord.getText();


        try 
        {
            int welke = Integer.parseInt(invoer);

            if  (welke-1 >0 && welke-1<5) 
            { 
                vraag.setText("Goeie keus!");
                if (welke == 1){ 

                    knop.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

                }
                knop.setBackground(Color.red);
            }
```

But now it only changes the last button to red which is created bij the array.

So the question can I select a button by its name?
So  if (input = 1) alter button 1 to green. in stead of only button 5.

I have tried de solution of gile, but i can't get it to work:

I get every time a: "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException"

```
package kiesknop;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

//public class Paneel extends JApplet
public class Paneel extends JFrame

{

private JPanel paneel;
private JButton knop;
public  JTextField antwoord;
private JLabel vraag;
public JButton[] knops;

public Paneel() {

    int [][] numButtons = new int [5][4];
    numButtons[0][0] = 50;
    numButtons[0][1] = 10;
    numButtons[0][2] = 10;
    numButtons[0][3] = 10;

    numButtons[1][0] = 100;
    numButtons[1][1] = 10;
    numButtons[1][2] = 30;
    numButtons[1][3] = 30;

    numButtons[2][0] = 200;
    numButtons[2][1] = 10;
    numButtons[2][2] = 50;
    numButtons[2][3] = 50;

    numButtons[3][0] = 300;
    numButtons[3][1] = 10;
    numButtons[3][2] = 100;
    numButtons[3][3] = 100;

    numButtons[4][0] = 500;
    numButtons[4][1] = 10;
    numButtons[4][2] = 200;
    numButtons[4][3] = 200;

    String [] Titel = new String [5];

    Titel [0] = "*";
    Titel [1] = "**";
    Titel [2] = "***";
    Titel [3] = "****";
    Titel [4] = "*****";

    String [] tel = new String [5];
    tel [0] = "a";
    tel [1] = "b";
    tel [2] = "c";
    tel [3] = "d";
    tel [4] = "e";

paneel = new JPanel();

JButton[] knops = new JButton[5];

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            knops[i] = new JButton(Titel[i]);
            knops[i].setName (tel[i]);
            knops[i].setBounds(numButtons[i][0],numButtons[i][1], numButtons[i][2], numButtons[i][3]);
            knops[i].addActionListener(new KnopHandler());
        }

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    paneel.add(knops[i]);

}


vraag = new JLabel("Welke knop grootte vind je het mooist?");
vraag.setBounds(100, 400, 250, 20);

antwoord = new JTextField(20);
antwoord.setBounds(500, 400, 100, 20);
antwoord.setEditable(true);
antwoord.addActionListener(new AntwoordHandler());

paneel.add (vraag);
paneel.add (antwoord);

setContentPane (paneel);

    }
public class KnopHandler implements ActionListener  {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        JButton o = (JButton)e.getSource();
        String Text = o.getText();
        String name = o.getName();
        String Label =o.getLabel();

        System.out.println("knop gedrukt");
        System.out.println(Text);
        System.out.println(name);
        System.out.println(Label);  
    }
}

class AntwoordHandler  implements ActionListener  {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String invoer = antwoord.getText();


        try 
        {
            int welke = Integer.parseInt(invoer);

            if  (welke >0 && welke<5) 
            { 
                vraag.setText("Goeie keus!");
                if(welke == 1)// knops[welke].setBackground(Color.BLUE);
                System.out.println(knops[1]);

                if(welke == 2) knops[welke].setBackground(Color.BLUE);

                if(welke == 3) knops[welke].setBackground(Color.BLUE);

                if(welke == 4) knops[welke].setBackground(Color.BLUE);

                if(welke == 5) knops[welke].setBackground(Color.BLUE);
                }

            else vraag.setText("Geen geldige invoer!");
            }

            catch( NumberFormatException nfe)
            {
                if( invoer.equals("")) vraag.setText("Niets ingevuld!");
                    else 
                vraag.setText("Alleen nummers invoeren!");
            }

        }
    }


public static void main (String arg[])

{

JFrame frame = new Paneel();
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setLayout(null);
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.setSize(900, 500);


}
}
```

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) *"when i type in a number in a Jtextfield."*  So primitive.  Use a `JSpinner` instead.

Comment: I will read the SSCCE guidlines, about the JSpinner i will look in to it (i Just started with Java)

Comment: *"I will read the SSCCE guidlines,"*  I prefer to think of them as 'tips' though SO seems to have upgraded them to 'guidelines' (unfortunately) *"about the JSpinner"*  Good, but let's not stop us from solving this without one. Maybe pencil it in as 'To-Do' - for later.

Comment: JButton[] knops = new JButton[5]; had to be knops = new JButton[5]; and now it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put buttons in an array

```
JButton[] knops = new JButton[5];
...
knops[i] = new JButton(Titel[i]);
...
```

And then set the background after user entered a number:

```
if (welke == 1){ 
    knops[welke].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your title doesn't match with the given example: *you are asking to get a button reference with string name but you are trying to parse the name to an integer.*

However, if i understood your requirement correctly: I can think of two option:

1. Traverse each button of the button's array you have and compare with their name with your target name: you can get the name of the component(JButton) invoking `button.getName()`.
2. Instead of using array which require traverse each time to get the target button with matching name, Create a `HashMap<key, value>`: `HashMap<String, JButton>`, map the button to their name and use it to get the component on Action Event.

   ```
     HashMap<String, JButton>buttomMap = new HashMap<>();
     buttonMap.put("kicker", kickerButton); // kickButton is a button
     //// Then in actionPerformed() function
     JButton button = buttonMap.get("kicker");
     button.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
   ```